# How to stop adding the same person again in FaceAPI persongroup

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition, face-api

Is there a way to stop adding the same person in the FaceAPI persongroup?
The problem is users who are already in the persongroup are adding themselves with different names.

Below is the method I wrote. It returns the person GUID that is being added to the person group.

```
public async Task<Guid> Register(IEnumerable<MediaFile> photos)
{
    var personGroupId = "XYXNXNX"

    var allPersonGroups = await _faceServiceClient.ListPersonGroupsAsync();

    if (allPersonGroups?.Any(x => x.PersonGroupId == personGroupId) == false)
    {
        await _faceServiceClient.CreatePersonGroupAsync(personGroupId, "HFFGFGFD"); // creating a new person group if not exits.
    }

    foreach (var photo in photos)
    {
        using (var stream = photo.GetStream())
        {
            var faces = await _faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(stream);

            if (faces?.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new CustomException(_translatorService.NoFaceFound);
            }

            if (faces?.Length > 1)
            {
                throw new CustomException(_translatorService.MultipleFacesFound);
            }
        }
    }

    var person = await _faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync(personGroupId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    foreach (var photo in photos)
    {
        await _faceServiceClient.AddPersonFaceInPersonGroupAsync(personGroupId, person.PersonId, photo.GetStream());
    }

    await _faceServiceClient.TrainPersonGroupAsync(personGroupId);

    return person.PersonId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### What you did

Based on your code, you are doing the following:

1. Get a `PersonGroup` by its `PersonGroupId` or creating if not
   existing
2. Then for each photos provided in the method parameters:

   - Detect if there are faces using `Detect` method from Face API: if 0 or more than 1 found, throw an Exception
3. Create a new `Person`, added to the previous `PersonGroup`
4. Then for each photos provided in the method parameters: add the face to the created Person
5. Finally, train the `PersonGroup`

### Avoiding to create new `Person` for existing persons

If you want to avoid to create a new `Person` if you already have photos of the face of the same person, you can simply call the method `Identify` with one of the photos (any of them if you know that all are from the same person, as your code seems to suggest).

This step should be done before the following line:

```
var person = await _faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync(personGroupId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Here you could do something like this (I used the methods from the latest Nuget Package for Face API, available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face/):

```
public async Task<Guid> Register(IEnumerable<MediaFile> photos)
{
    var personGroupId = "XYXNXNX";

    var allPersonGroups = await _faceClient.PersonGroup.ListAsync();

    if (allPersonGroups?.Any(x => x.PersonGroupId == personGroupId) == false)
    {
        await _faceClient.PersonGroup.CreateAsync(personGroupId, "HFFGFGFD"); // creating a new person group if not exits.
    }

    var facesIdFromPhotos = new List<Guid>();

    foreach (var photo in photos)
    {
        using (var stream = photo.GetStream())
        {
            var faces = await _faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(stream);

            if (faces?.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("NoFaceFound");
            }

            if (faces?.Length > 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("MultipleFacesFound");
            }

            facesIdFromPhotos.Add(((Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face.Models.DetectedFace)faces[0]).FaceId);
        }
    }

    // Check similarity, with 1 face from the previous detected faces
    var similarityPerson = await _faceClient.Face.IdentifyAsync(facesIdFromPhotos.Take(1).ToList(), personGroupId);

    Guid targetPersonId;
    if (similarityPerson[0].Candidates?.Count > 0)
    {
        targetPersonId = similarityPerson[0].Candidates[0].PersonId;
    }
    else
    {
        var createdPerson = await _faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.CreateAsync(personGroupId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        targetPersonId = createdPerson.PersonId;
    }

    // Add faces to Person (already existing or not)
    foreach (var photo in photos)
    {
        await _faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.AddFaceFromStreamAsync(personGroupId, targetPersonId, photo.GetStream());
    }

    await _faceClient.PersonGroup.TrainAsync(personGroupId);

    return targetPersonId;
}
```

Last thing: why are you throwing an exception? Can't you just skip the photos with 0 or more than 1 face?

Comment: With this approach, I can't add a person who is a similar lookalike of the already registered person. The IdentifyAsync is returning the already registered person while I am trying to register a lookalike.

Comment: Of course you can, by using the confidence score in `Identify` result. If the new person is similar but not the same person, you just have to use a confidence score high enough, and you will be under the value